# devextreme partial text color react

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

Is there any possiblity to display partial color to the string the devextreme data grid cell.
For example values which are greather than 5000 should be in red and rest should have default color.

Eg:
The devextreme datagrid has a cell with value "4995,4218,4445,4506,5145". I need to show only 5145 as red and rest values should not apply any color, because only 5145 is there 5000.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [cell template](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Columns/Customize_Cells/#Customize_the_Appearance) to accomplish this.

```html
<DataGrid>
    <Column
        dataField="myValues"
        cellRender={renderGridCell}
    />
</DataGrid>
```

```js
const renderGridCell = (cellData) => {
    return (
        // this is just an example. access the cellData parameter to get the values of your object
        [4995,4218,4445,4506,5145]
            .map(x => <span style={{ backgroundColor: x > 5000 ? 'red' : undefined }}>{x}</span>)
            .reduce((acc, x) => acc === null ? x : <>{acc}, {x}</>, null)
    );
}
```

Here is the cell data [parameter description](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#cellRender). You probably need to access `cellData.value` or `cellData.data`.

[image: cellRender-example]

Comment: if the partial text should be shown at summary level then does the cellTemplate would work? because using cellTemplate will update when rowType is data and not groupby. If we use groupCelltemplate then it applies for grouping column, but my column is not grouped.

Comment: your are right. my example only works for data cells. Unfortunately i have no experience in customizing the summary cells. This is not well supported by the library. I found this thread, maybe it helps: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t592543/datagrid-how-to-colorize-summary-value-at-runtime